# Python and Gdata: add contact to a group does not works

Tags: python, contacts, gdata-api

i'm trying to use contacts api via python in order to add a contact to a group in Gmail.
This is my group retrieves with [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contact_groups)

```
Atom Id: http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/user%40gmail.com/base/6d1fccc00a474e6c
Group Name: Newsletter
Last Updated: 2012-04-17T14:04:51.565Z
Extended Properties: Self
Link: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/user%40gmail.com/full/6d1fccc00a474e6c
Edit Link: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/user%40gmail.com/full/6d1fccc00a474e6c
ETag: "QHs9fTVSLit7I2A9WhVXFkoLQw0."
```

so i'm trying to use this code ispiring to [changing group membership](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#changing_group_membership)

```
def add_group_membership(gd_client, contact_url, group_atom_id):
  contact = gd_client.GetContact(contact_url)
  contact.group_membership_info.append(gdata.contacts.data.GroupMembershipInfo(href=group_atom_id))
  try:
    updated_contact = gd_client.Update(contact)
    return updated_contact
  except gdata.client.RequestError, e:
    if e.status == 412:
      # Etags mismatch: handle the exception.
      pass
  return None
```

but

```
add_group_membership(gd_client, contact_url, 'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/user%40gmail.com/base/6d1fccc00a474e6c')
```

respons

```
gdata.client.RequestError: Server responded with: 404, Group not found.
```

my contact = gd_client.GetContact(contact_url) is right

```
<ns0:entry xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" ns1:etag="&quot;Rn04fTVSLyt7I2A9WhJQEkQKRwI.&quot;">[...]<ns2:edited>2012-07-26T08:07:47.335Z</ns2:edited></ns0:entry>
```

What's wrong?